# Code colors in Html using CSS or javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a website and I teach Java on it.
I know html and css if it helps..

I have lectures in my site and in my lectures there are descriptions: in the description I write code sometimes so I made a class for code so everytime I type code I do  and it looks good, but not perfect.

I want to make specific words to be bold and in blue or pink color for example.
Is there a way to do it? maybe with javascript?

I know I can create a new class for special words and then to do  for example but this will be too much job to write this span every time that it's not worth it.

So is there a way to do it maybe with html5 or js? Thank you.

edit: I use the usefedora.com platform so it's more difficult to do it, does somebody knows how to do it on usefedora's platform?

Comment: I use https://highlightjs.org/

Answer (score 2):

the thing you are searching for is a codemirror. There are many codemirrors but only one of them is called codemirror.

[Code Mirror](http://codemirror.net/)

There are also solutions that don't require you to write any javascript, using web components.

[Prism.js](http://component.kitchen/components/prism-js)

Here is one that's insanely trivial to use

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of code to html converters which do syntax highlighting if that's what your looking for e.g.

http://tohtml.com/java/

or

http://hilite.me/

You can take this HTML and use it on your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can also download a jQuery plugin. [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) is very popular.

The way they work is that you copy the files to your website, and then you just put your code into a  tag, and the plugin automatically beautifies your code.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend choosing one of these libraries- [PrismJS](http://prismjs.com/%20PrismJS), [Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/), or [Rainbow](http://craig.is/making/rainbows).

Each is designed for exactly this purpose. You just put your code into the web page, inside an HTML5 `code` tag decorated with the language name. They will automatically format your code with the necessary markup to attach color styles to. No need for any external tools. The first two provide their own styles as well, the last assumes you'll write your own.